# Which Bemani rhythm game in the arcades has the strictest timing window?

Tags: rhythm-game

Konami has a rhythm game division called '[Bemani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bemani_series)'. In it, there are currently a total of 10 titles or so that are in production in arcades all over the world (well, mostly in Japan but there's one or two in the USA as well as hundreds around Asia; there are console versions too).

Anyway my question is, **which game(s) in the Bemani series have the strictest timing window for the highest judgement score, and what is that timing window**? In StepMania for example, the highest judgement score is 'Marvelous', with a default of 16.667ms timing window between that and 'Perfect'. However, I'm not asking about StepMania or its variants - I just want to know about the official ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some research on the Japanese inter-webs and concluded the following:

Dance Dance Revolution currently holds the title of having the tightest timing window at 15ms.
This is closely followed by アイカツ！, which is no longer in service, at 17ms.
beatmaniaIIDX is in the third place at 20ms.

The rest are as follows:
pop'n music: 25 ms
REFLEC BEAT: 25 ms
drummania: 27 ms
GUITARFREAKS: 33 ms
SOUND VOLTEX: 33 ms
DanceEvolution Arcade: 33 ms
ミライダガッキ: 33 ms
Beatstream: 33 ms
Taiko no Tatsujin (Namco): 33 ms
maimai (Sega): 33 ms
Project DIVA arcade (Sega): 33 ms
jubeat: 42 ms

[Source with the original sources for each game](http://544332133981.hatenablog.com/entry/bemani-rank_4)